# What will be "session_memcached_host:" when I use Memcache service provided by Google Cloud Application Flex. Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memcached, app-engine-flexible, symfony5

I am evaluating Symfony 5.0.1 with Google Cloud Application Flexible Engine.

I couldn't use Memcache service provided in App Engine because I don't know which "memcached_host" should be used. 
  [Memcache in Application Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNPa.png)

I tried using "session_memcached_host:localhost" in services.yaml but it doesn't work

Same Project of Symfony is tested locally and it works well with local Memcache server (in my local setup).

Comment: You have mentioned "Memcache service provided in App Engine" however, in App Engine Flex documentation. Could you please elaborate more on that ? Which one exactly are you trying to use ? Are you following a specific official tutorial or community tutorial ?

Comment: I am referring to the option "Memcache" provided in App Engine menu items, please refer screen shot "Memcache in Application Engine" in my question, please refer this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/memcache/using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example of a PHP app using memcache](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php55/memcache) on Google App Engine Standard.

[Here specifically](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php55/memcache/app.php) you can see how you should configure memcache to work on App Engine

I have tried the example above myself and it's working as expected.

> **NOTE:** You have mentioned App Engine Flex but provided examples and docs on
>   Standard.

Memcache is currently generally available for App Engine Standard.

Please keep in mind that there are huge differences between App Engine Flex and Standard.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I overlooked the differences (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) at first places.

Answer (score 0):

I am not App Engine expert but looking at the example below it appears you can directly call it from your code. Everything is preconfigured and you can just call it directly from your code. See the link below for further information:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/appengine-memcache-service-google-cloud-platform-8214ee9eada1

Comment: API available only for Java & Python. Symfony is based on PHP and it uses session handler to store sessions in cache